# EmberJS - Transitioning to parent route renders a blank template

Tags: templates, ember.js

I am trying to transition back to a parent route in Ember. Instead of the expected template only a blank template appears to be rendered with no errors being thrown.

Here's a fiddle: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yiredoge/25/edit?html,js,output

In "Admin" > "Menu Item 1" > "Edit Item 1", when I click back on "Menu Item 1", a blank template appears to be rendered instead of the "item1" template I was expecting.

Likewise the same issue occurs in "Admin" > "Menu Item 2" > "Edit Item 2" and then clicking back on "Menu Item 2".

I'm new to Ember so no doubt this is the intended behaviour and I'm doing something wrong but I can't seem to pick it apart using the documentation.

Many thanks.

Comment: probably its because u use a custom outlet. Your route hierarchy should be the same then your layout hierarchy. If u wanna render the item1 OR the edit, then put the stuff from item1 to item1/index. If u want to render it simultaniously then use another {{outlet}} inside the item1 template. Item1 wont be rerendered because u dont leave it when u go to item1/edit. U just leave item1/index!

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yiredoge/27/edit

Comment: Thank you both. I created an item1/index template, which solved the problem.